# Level of certainty in "intend" versus "hope"

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

I am trying to write an essay detailing my short and long term goals and I want to convey to the reader that these are goals that I fully intend on achieving. I was going to say "I intend, not hope" but I am unsure if the level of certainty conveyed by both word is the same or not.
Would that sentence work as desired if used as a title?

Comment: Why don't you post the entire sentence, or better yet, the whole paragraph, so we'd have more context to base our assessment on which, in turn, will put us in a better position to advise you, dude.

Comment: "I intend to achieve" is far more certain and committed than "I hope to achieve", if I have understood your question correctly.

Comment: @Ricky Its for the title so it will be by itself and not in a paragraph

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I want to contrast how one would normally hope to complete the task on time but I, however, fully intend on completing it in time.

Comment: The fact that a person sets a long-term goal means they've moved beyond simple hope. I would venture to say that all or most, not just you, fully intend to achieve any long-term goals they set. If something is just a hope or a wish, then it generally doesn't get expressed as a goal. I only say this because you run the risk of sounding arrogant and even condescending--like you assume that you take your goals more seriously than others. Any reader will feel such insult come through the page the page at them. It will compromise the efficacy of your essay, so I'd advise you to rethink your tack.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Wow I did not think of it that way. I certainly did not intend on being condescending. Thanks for the feedback!
I will, however, leave this open in case someone else has the same question.

Comment: @Najm Sheikh : I suspected that you didn't intend to be condescending.  Often, it's all to easy to inadvertently create an unintended tone in writing.  Anyway, I'm glad I could be of help.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at the definitions:

> [**intend**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intend?s=t): to have in mind as something to be done or brought about
>
> [**hope**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hope?s=t): to feel that something desired may happen

Not quite as clear as I'd hoped, but hey. The key difference here is that **intend** carries the connotation that *you* are going to do something about it. Hence, "I hope to win" means "I desire to be the best", whereas "I intend to win" means "I'm am going to try to be the best".

In terms of level of certainty: I don't think either word signifies more, in and of itself. But if it is something that you have some control of, it's more much more likely to happen if you do something about it! That said, with the "I hope/intend to win" example you are always dependant on other people not doing well enough, hence why "intend" doesn't carry certainty.

A title for an essay of **"I intend, not hope"**, means "I don't just sit around waiting for things I want: if I want them I go and make sure they happen!" I think it's a great title for an essay on your personal goals.